# My Postgres Master POD takes maximum CPU Cores which crashes the entire dependent PODS

Tags: database, postgresql, cpu

When I'm running my Backend and Posrgres Master POD is given 25 Cores

```
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 25000m
          memory: 140Gi
        requests:
          cpu: 25000m
```

After around 3-4 Hours of running the Postgres Master POD starts to take a lot of CPU until it reaches the Maximum

[image]

Here are my Postgres Settings:

```
          effective_cache_size: "105GB"
          effective_io_concurrency: "200"
          listen_addresses: '*'
          log_destination: "stderr"
          logging_collector: "false"
          log_line_prefix: '%t [%p]: [%l-1] [trx_id=%x] user=%u,db=%d'
          log_min_error_statement: "DEBUG1"
          log_error_verbosity: "verbose"
          maintenance_work_mem: "2GB"
          max_connections: "4000"
          max_wal_size: "16GB"
          min_wal_size: "4GB"
          max_worker_processes: "18"
          max_parallel_workers_per_gather: "9"
          max_parallel_workers: "18"
          max_parallel_maintenance_workers: "4"
          random_page_cost: "1.1"
          shared_bufIfers: "35GB"
          shared_preload_libraries: "pg_stat_statements"
          pg_stat_statements.track: "all"
          log_statement: "all"
          synchronous_commit: "false"
          syslog_facility: "LOCAL0"
          syslog_ident: "postgres"
          syslog_sequence_numbers: "true"
          syslog_split_messages: "true"
          wal_buffers: "16MB"
          work_mem: "500MB"
          checkpoint_completion_target: "0.9"
          idle_in_transaction_session_timeout: "20000"
          statement_timeout: "60000"
```

Also ,when checking number of idle/active processes ,we get:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this ? What might cause this high CPU Postgres usage ?

Comment: I would try reducing the following parameters:
max_worker_processes and parallesim, effective_io_concurrency.

Also work_mem value is too high. If 4000 connections are established, the system will crash due to lack of memory.

Comment: What is a "master POD"?  You should tag your question with whatever it is that explains this jargon.